# Guard - Minitest, Rubocop and Infinity Loops

Tags: minitest, guard, rubocop

I am using Guard with Minitest and Rubocop (with autocorrect).

I end up with an infinite loop.  Where Rubocop keeps trying to change the controller and then runs the tests again etc. and so on.  This error message also gets thrown when this happens.  If I run just RC or Minitest then there is no loop - each runs fine independently.

```
0 files inspected, 13 offenses detected, 6 offenses corrected, 7 offenses auto-correctable
Infinite loop detected in /Users/aximus/Development/oilfieldtracker/app/controllers/locations_controller.rb and caused by Lint/AssignmentInCondition, Metrics/AbcSize, Metrics/ClassLength, Metrics/MethodLength, Style/Documentation, Style/DoubleCopDisableDirective
```

I am new to guard / RC and MT - am I missing an obvious setting here? I know I need to clean up my complex controllers but for now I just want the basics fixed and my tests to run. I can come back to refactor in depth later.

Comment: This seems like a bug in RuboCop, so I'd suggest you try take Minitest and Guard out the equation and try find out the minimal set of code in your `locations_controller.rb` to trigger the error. Run RuboCop directly from the comand line.

Also make sure your RuboCop is up to date in case this has been fixed in a newer version.

Comment: I need to clarify my question. I mean a loop with Guard and Minitest (that error message only appears when the loop happens. RB runs the the tests then RB then test over and over.